# Get yourself decent containers

Tags: pronouns, reflexive-pronouns

I was watching a cooking show and the guy in the show said "get yourself decent containers" Why not just to say get decent containers?

What does yourself mean with a verb get?

Answer (score 3):

This phrase, *to get oneself (a thing)*, is usually used as part of a set of instructions, particularly in a very informal environment.  When I've heard and used it, it is most often part of the following, which includes two parts that are not immediately obvious to a nonnative speaker, the verb *want* used in an imperative sense, and the phrase that you asked about.

> *You'll want* **to get yourself** X.

This means

> *You should* **get** X **for yourself**.

The implication is that you do not current have decent containers for (whatever the host was cooking) and that purchasing them is a worthwhile investment that will make the job easier and/or more successful.  The speaker is usually an expert, or at least considers him or herself to be an expert, and is speaking to a novice.

There is a completely separate usage that is similar, but instead of *to get oneself (a thing)* it is *to get oneself to (a place)*.  In this case, it is an imperative sentence telling you to go somewhere.  It would only be used in informal conversation as well, as in the following:

> John, your alarm didn't go off.  You need *to get yourself to school* in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

**Yourself** is a **reflexive pronoun** and is used for **emphasis** in your example.

> You will want to get some good containers.
>   You will need some good containers.
>   Some good containers will be necessary.

All have the same meaning and can be used in both **written and spoken** conversation

> You'll want to get **yourself** some good containers

Was used to emphasize **attention** by the TV host since he was **talking to** you.

Comment: Though they can be used in written and spoken conversation, as you say, it's a somewhat informal construct. I don't think we'd find this very often in, say, a textbook.